# Outlook Re-Install - remove the new PST file

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007

I re-installed Windows Vista and Office/Outlook 2007 in order to get a bigger C Drive.
When I re-installed Outlook, it never seems to ask me if I have an existing PST, and always creates a new one.

I can access my old PST files, and add them to my new outlook.  But - how do I get rid of the new unwanted PST file and make all the emails go to my original PST file?

I spent a while "googling" but so far have not found the solution.

Thanks,

Neal

Comment: Not a programming question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest fix is probably to just import the mail from your old PST to the new one.  If you don't want to do that for some reason (maybe your old PST has tons of mail, etc) then the following steps should work.  I don't have a Vista machine with Outlook installed for reference, but here is how it works on Windows XP.  I assume it's probably exactly the same, or at least very similar:

1. Close Outlook
2. **MAKE SURE** you have a backup of your PST before doing anything
3. Go to Start | Control Panel
4. Double-click the Mail icon
5. Click the "Data Files" button

   [image]
6. Click the "Add" button, then browse to your *OLD* PST file and add it so you can add it to the data file list.

   [image]
7. Highlight your *OLD* PST file in the list, then click the "Set as Default" button to tell Outlook you want the mail to be delivered there.

   [image]
8. Remove the *NEW* PST file that Outlook created if you wish.

Close all dialogs, then start Outlook again.  New mail should now go to your *OLD* PST.

Comment: Thanks for the screen shots.  I think I had done this before, but it had been a year or two.  You can also click in Outlook on Tools, then Account Settings to get to the same screens.

Answer (score 0):

If the old PST is compatible with Outlook 2007, just replace the new Outlook.pst by the old one.

To find out where Outlook.pst is, right-click in Outlook on "Personal Folders", select Properties and click on "Advanced...". Then close Outlook, rename the existing Outlook.pst to something else, then copy the old Outlook.pst in its place.

If Outlook refuses to accept this file, rename back Outlook.pst and follow the advice given by Tim Lara.

Comment: Not the best answer for me.  I'm dealing with large PST files over one gig on different disks.  I didn't ask how to move the files around, I asked how to make mail go to the my original PST file.